# link list insertion sort and reducing polynomials c++

Tags: c++, insertion-sort

I am writing this program dealing with polynomials. I am having trouble with the last part of my assignment. I need to sort the polynomials by degrees, then be able to reduce the polynomial if there is a double degree in the polynomial. The code i have written below has segmentation fault for both functions. In my `void reduce(poly &p1)` my error occurs at `zc= zc->next`. Is there a different way of approaching completing these functions? plus im using link lists for my polynomials

```
class Poly{
private :
  struct term{
    double coef ;
    unsigned exp ;
    term *next ;
  } *term_t ;
public :
  Poly( ) ;
  void insert ( float c, int e ) ;
  void isort( Poly &p1);
  void reduce (Poly &p1);
  ~Poly( ) ;
} ;
void Poly :: isort ( Poly & p1){
  term *z;
  term * zc;
  term *c;
  if ( term_t == NULL && p1.term_t == NULL )
    return ;
  while (p1.term_t != NULL){
    c=p1.term_t;
    p1.term_t = p1.term_t->next;
    while (p1.term_t!=NULL && c->exp > zc->exp){
      z->coef = c->coef;
      z->exp=c->exp;
      c=c->next;
    }
    z.printPoly();
    zc->exp = z->exp;
    z=z->next;
    //c=c->next;
  }
}
void Poly :: reduce (Poly & p1){
  term *z ;
  if ( term_t == NULL && p1.term_t == NULL )
    return ;
  term *temp1;
  temp1 = p1.term_t ;
  while ( temp1 != NULL ){
    if ( term_t == NULL ){
      term_t = new term ;
      z = term_t ;
    }
    else{
      z -> next = new term ;
      z = z -> next ;
    }
    if (temp1 -> exp == z->exp)
      temp1->coef= temp1-> coef + z->coef;
    z->coef = temp1 -> coef;
    z->exp = temp1->exp;
    temp1=temp1->next;
  }
  while ( temp1 != NULL ){
    if ( term_t == NULL ){
      term_t = new term ;
      z = term_t ;
    }
    else{
      z -> next = new term ;
      z = z -> next ;
    }
    z -> coef = temp1 -> coef ;
    z -> exp = temp1 -> exp ;
    temp1 = temp1 -> next ;
  }
  z -> next = NULL ;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you said it was homework in the question, but you should also use the `[homework]` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::list` or `std::vector` or some other [STL container](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/)